# How to save Unity file that is readible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, save

I am saving state of simulation every Update function. It is just a list of ints indicating quantity of population that I got. Every Update I add current quantity of population to the list, and if quantity is 0, I stop executing and save the list in the file. Everything is allright, but what I got in my save state is this:

˘   ˘                                                         
                                                                       
                                                                                                                       
Is it possible to have it saved "normally" i.e. something like this: 5,6,7,10,12,3,0? I know how to decode it during loading in program but it's not the case. I want to read the txt file normally to extract it, so that I can make a plot out of it.
Here's a saving code:

```
    public static void saveData (List<int> data){

        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/dane.txt";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        DataToSave datatosave = new DataToSave(data);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, datatosave);
        stream.Close();
    }

}
```

And here is the DataToSave that I used before:

```
public class DataToSave {

    List<int> data;

    public DataToSave (List<int> list){
        data = list;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add `using System.io;` at the top.

Then, simply:

`string path = @(Application.persistentDataPath + "/dane.txt");`

`System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, string.Join(", ", data));`

See this link for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file

Comment: Careful: **Never** use `+ "/"` for directly concatenating system file paths. Rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which automatically uses the correct path separator symbol depending on the target platform.